# Zabbix pre-processing item get item within an array with javascript

Tags: api, zabbix

I don't have any experience with Javascript so I'm reaching out for the community to accomplish the below.
I have a few API calls configured on Zabbix which are working just fine. The thing is, not all of the results within an item is importante for me so I need to grab just what I want out of the array.

I'm using the pre-processing option on Zabbix to grab what I'm after but I can't get the code correct.

For instance, the below is one of the results Zabbix is getting.

```
[
{
    "batteryLife": "15 minutes",
    "communityString": "public",
    "instanceId": "260596.1",
    "instanceName": "UPS-01",
    "ipAddress": "10.1.100.44",
    "modelNumber": "GXT4-10000RT230",
    "name": "UPS-01",
    "objectType": "ScUps",
    "scName": "pth-pf-04",
    "scSerialNumber": 260596,
    "serialNumber": "unknown",
    "status": "Up",
    "statusDescription": "Online",
    "type": "Liebert"
}
```

]

How Can I Use the pre-processing to grab just the "ipAddress" value for instance?

Thanks for the help.
PeteF

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid JavaScript preprocessing where you can use JSONPath preprocessing, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/preprocessing/jsonpath_functionality

In your case:

```
$[0].ipAddress
```

A useful tool for JSONPath is http://jsonpath.com/

Comment: I personally didn't know about this other option in Zabbix. I will try it out. Thanks for the useful links.

Comment: I confirm that what you posted worked in my case and I also learned something new. Thanks for showing this other way which is way easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone have the same doubt as I was having here is how I got it working to return the "ipAdress" value

```
var json = JSON.parse(value);
return json.ipAddress;
```

In case there are more than one dictionary inside of an array.

```
var json = JSON.parse(value);
return json[0].ipAddress;
```